# Enjoyed your dance vs enjoyed your dancing

Tags: grammaticality

> I absolutely enjoyed your dance.

Vs

> I absolutely enjoyed your dancing.

/If I were to ignore the word performance./

What’s the difference?

Answer (score 2):

**dance** refers to the choreographed "work", the artistic presentation, the performance as an aesthetic unity.

**dancing** refers to the dancer's movement and performance.

Comment: True, but if my niece asked me, "What did you think?" after I'd attended her dance recital, I think I could say either one of the OP's sentences and they would be interpreted as largely one in the same. Put another way, if I answered, "I absolutely enjoyed your dancing," I'd be very surprised if she replied, "Yes, but what about the dance?"

Comment: How can we tell the dancer from the dance?

Comment: Yes, my point exactly.

Comment: I bet you could say to your niece, *I didn't really get that part of the dance where the lead dancer moves across the floor as though she's walking barefoot on very hot sand, but I really liked your dancing.*